# BASH: sending commands to ftp and validating status codes

Tags: bash, ftp

I want to write a bash script that runs ftp on background. I want to some way send commands to it and receive responses. For example a want run ftp, then sent it

```
user username pass
cd foo
ls
binary
mput *.html
```

and receive status codes and verify them. I tried to do it this way

```
tail -n 1 -f in | ftp -n host >> out &
```

and then reading out file and verifying. But it doesn't work. Can somebody show me the right way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: It's simple, I just want to copy some files to server using ftp. But I need some conditions what to do depending on messages getting from server (for example, if this file is older than some date, replacing it) and error handling also (if ftp error code occurs, delete all uploaded files). I thought that running ftp command on background and supplying it with commands and reading back messages is solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd run one set of commands, check the output, and then run the second set in reaction to the output. You could use [here-documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for the command sets and [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to capture the output in a variable, e.g. like this:

```
output=$(cat <<EOF | ftp -n host
user username pass
cd foo
ls
binary
mput *.html
EOF
)

if [[ $output =~ "error message" ]]; then
  # do stuff
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful answer. And how can I run for example only 3 commands, check output and then do another set of commands with ftp? I want to keep ftp process/program running (on background maybe?) and "communicate" with it. In other words I want to send some command to ftp, read back output, decide what to do next, send some more commands to ftp...

Comment: Why do you want to "talk" to the FTP server instead of simply running the commands as separate processes one after the other?